# how to find ellipse's minor axis and BC segment?

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

[image]the picture depicts a cone and the red line is ellipse's major axis.

I found the major axis to be $\frac{rh^2}{l^3}\sqrt{l^2+3h^2}$ which is calculated using Pythagorean rule, Thales' theorem and Trigonometry.

but I don't know how to find the minor axis.

Is there any way?

Also, I need to find $BC$ segment in order to find the difference between the ellipse's center and the point that the cone's height goes through the ellipse. How come?

Comment: See at the end of this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3102248/is-the-right-intersection-of-an-oblique-circular-cone-an-ellipse/3103027#3103027

Comment: so here, $BD$ and $AE$ are the two parallel lines in my picture like in your answer in that question. true?

Comment: Yes, exactly so. Take also into account that $b$ is half the minor axis.

Comment: @Aretino I have edited the picture to ask another question too. Are $AB$ and $AC$ the same in length? ($C$ isn't the ellipse's center and $AC$ is on the height).

Comment: No, they are not the same.

Comment: so how to calculate $BC$?

Comment: But why do you need $BC$?

Comment: in order to find the difference between ellipse's center and the point that cone's height goes through the ellipse

Comment: can you please answer these two questions too? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3572719/are-semi-minor-axes-the-same-when-we-have-these-different-major-axes https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3566483/how-to-find-the-ellipse-perimeter-and-equation-using-this

Comment: Please edit your question with the new request to find $BC$.

Comment: I did it @Aretino

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that triangles $ARH$, $RHE$, $HEM$, $EMB$, $MBN$ are all similar among them. Hence:
$$
HE={h\over l}r,\quad ME={h^2\over l^2}r,\quad 
BM={h^3\over l^3}r,\quad BN={h^4\over l^4}r. 
$$ 
Semi-minor axis is then (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3102248/is-the-right-intersection-of-an-oblique-circular-cone-an-ellipse/3103027#3103027) for a proof):
$$
b=\sqrt{EM\cdot BN}={h^3\over l^3}r=BM.
$$

Triangles $CMD$ and $CNB$ are similar too, which entails:
$$
{BC\over CD}={BN\over DM}={BN\over ME}={h^2\over l^2}.
$$
From that, and using your result for $BD$, it is easy to find $BC$.

[image]

Comment: thank you for your answer. in your picture, the triangle $ABC$ is more likely to be equilateral. aren't $AC$ and $AB$ really the same? and from your last fractions, it is stated that I have to have the length of $CD$ in order to have $BC$. is it true?

Comment: It doesn't matter if $ABC$ is isosceles or not. And you know the sum $BC+CD$, hence can compute $CD$.

Comment: If $ABC$ is isosceles, then we can compute $BC$ using law of cosines. and, yes, I know $BC+CD$; but when I don't know $BC$, how can I compute $CD$? my goal is to compute $BC$.

Comment: If one knows both $BC+ CD$ and $BC/CD$ it's easy.

Comment: $${BC+CD\over BC}=1+{CD\over BC}=1+{l^2\over h^2}.$$

Comment: is the same things applicable to the following question? (let the intersection of semi-major axes be $O$. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3572719/are-semi-minor-axes-the-same-when-we-have-these-different-major-axes